# Plantilla de mapeo appsync amplify

Tags: aws, amplify, appsync

Tengo una api graphql con aws appsync debido a que estoy usando amplify en una app. Estoy teniendo problemas con crear un plantilla de mapeo ya que no me está funcionando y retorna null siempre.

Tengo un modelo graphql para post que contiene el campo **like** que es del siguiente tipo:

```
type Like @model @key(fields: ["userId", "postId"])
@key(name: "byPost", fields: ["postId"], queryField: "likesByPost")
@auth(rules:[
  { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete] },
  { allow: private, operations: [read] }
]){
  userId: ID!
  user: User! @connection(fields: ["userId"])
  postId: ID!
}
```

por lo tanto la clave principal es userId y postId. Mi plantilla contiene el siguiente codigo en la especificación de petición(req):

```
## [Start] Set the primary @key. **
#set( $modelObjectKey = {
  "userId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB($util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($ctx.args.input.userId, "___xamznone____")),
  "postId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB($util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($ctx.source.id, "___xamznone____"))
} )
## [End] Set the primary @key. **
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "operation": "GetItem",
  "key": $util.toJson($modelObjectKey)
}
```

Este solucionador esta especificado para PostResponse.like por lo tanto el objetivo es que al obtener un post determinar si el usuario que hizo la petición le ha dado like, para esto hace una consulta a la tabla like con los parametros `$ctx.args.input.userId` que el id del usuario que se envía en la petición y `$ctx.source.id` que sería el id del post. Este ultimo enfoque que obtiene el id del post es valido ya que en otras plantillas utilizo el mismo principio de acceder al objeto source, lo que veo como unica diferencia es que en este caso PostResponse se resuelve con una llamada lambda y no se si por el hecho de que una llamada lambda sea la petición principal esto me quita el acceso a los argumentos de la petición (se que acceder al objeto source esta correcto ya que tengo una plantilla que lo utiliza para obtener el campo PostResponse.user apartir de `$ctx.source.userId` que sería el usuario que creó el post)

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunas pruebas y note que `$ctx.args` es un objeto vacio por lo que no funciona como esperaba. Realmente es un desastre depurar las plantillas de mapeo vtl. He llegado a la conclusión de que `$ctx.args` no siempre tiene los parametros de la petición como pensaba sino que tiene los parametros del campo, por lo tanto, solo aplica para el campo principal en mi caso `PostResponse` entonces el campo anidado `PostResponse.like` no tiene argumentos. Como lo que necesitaba es el acceso a id del usuario que hizo la petición encontré una solución alternativa debido a que uso Cognito lo que me permite obtener el id del usuario con `$ctx.identity.sub`.

```
## [Start] Set the primary @key. **
#set( $modelObjectKey = {
  "userId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB($util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($ctx.identity.sub, "___xamznone____")),
  "postId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB($util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($ctx.source.id, "___xamznone____"))
} )
## [End] Set the primary @key. **
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "operation": "GetItem",
  "key": $util.toJson($modelObjectKey)
}
```

Aunque solucioné el problema alternativamente me parece una gran limitante de las plantillas de mapeo, realmente sería muy potente hacer lo que intentaba. Quizás haya forma de pasar los argumentos a los resolutores anidados pero no he encontrado nada.